# More information when failing to bookmark a conversation in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, error-message, chat-bookmarks

Bookmarked conversations in chat have a limit of 400 messages. If you try to bookmark too many messages, you get the error:

[image: A conversation can only have up to 400 messages]

Can the error include how many messages I attempted to bookmark? Currently I keep making the conversation arbitrarily shorter until the error goes away

Comment: Easy solution: ***Count!***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fair enough; this goes out with the next chat build.

[image: bookmark rejection message including message count]

Comment: Nice, but what about client side restriction? :)