# Is it possible to bookmark a conversation in chat, which has messages in two different days?

Tags: support, chat, conversation, chat-bookmarks

I know that there is [400 messages limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109744/more-information-when-failing-to-bookmark-a-conversation-in-chat) for a conversation. But in rooms with low usage it is possible that an interesting conversation spans more than one day.

Is it somehow possible to bookmark a conversation which starts one days and ends the second day? If not, could something like this be implemented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's absolutely possible.

From within the live chat, the day doesn't matter anyway. But it also works from the transcript.

Go to the transcript of the day with the first message, and select it for a conversation bookmark:

[image: choosing the first message of the conversation]

Then switch the to the day with the last message. It will **remember the first message** you selected on the previous page, and you can then choose the last message:

[image: choosing the first message of the conversation, on a different day]

<sup>(ignore 3. on that screenshot, it's [no longer necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239484/make-it-more-obvious-that-you-can-bookmark-a-conversation-from-the-transcript-if/239559#239559))</sup>

You can also switch the order around, selecting the last message first.

Finally, you can also select one of the two messages from the transcript and one from the live chat in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. (I did not even notice that I can bookmark a conversation in live chat - I've always done this from transcript.)