# Can we add a feature enabling us to save our favorite chat messages in one place?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, permalink

I visit a number of different chat rooms where I find specific messages interesting. Because there are so many, and I tend to forget which room they came from, I'd like to be able to save them in one place. I think a tab on our Network Profile page would be best, as that's how we access all our favorite questions. I understand I can press Permalink and save those links in my browser, but that means if I want to read them, I have to leave the page I'm on and go searching through my bookmarks, each of which brings me to a single chat room highlighting only one favorite message. I also understand I can Star them, but, again, I have to remember which room they're in and search that room for those messages. I'd appreciate a way to keep them all together so I can easily find them.

Comment: Are you looking for the [bookmarking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160767/is-it-possible-to-bookmark-a-conversation-in-chat-which-has-messages-in-two-dif) functionality?

Comment: @rene: Yes, but I have now read the post which you link to, and yet I still can't find the bookmarking feature in the chat. Where is it and how to I access it?

Comment: Save the permalink in your browser's bookmarks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to save all your Permalinked messages in one place, for example in your profile? That's a feature I was going to ask for. If so, we could edit your question.

Comment: @Sue: Yes, I am looking for a feature like that. Please do edit my question.

Comment: I've re-worded the question. Please let me know if I didn't properly express your thoughts.

Comment: @Sue: Yes, all my thoughts are expressed very well there. Thank you for re-wording my question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create bookmarks of chat messages. Bookmarks can be a single message or a series of messages. Create a bookmark…

- from the live chat by clicking **room** → **create new bookmark**

  [image]
- from the transcript by clicking **bookmark a conversation**.

These bookmarks are not private though—they are accessible from the room's info page under the conversations tab. For more information on bookmarking, see the [relevant chat help section](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink).

Comment: Note, though, that these aren't per-user. They are visible to everyone with access to the room.

Comment: @AnnaLear Well, that's the same as [question favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248211/266359), isn't it?

Comment: @Shokhet not really, you can't see list of favorited questions by users in a site and when in a question, you can only see how many users favorited it but can't see who exactly. You need to view a specific profile to see what questions that user favorited. Not a big deal, but not the same either. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Fair enough.